# What happens if a bounty is not awarded before grace period, on a self-answered question?

Tags: support, bounty

Consider this scenario: One user starts a bounty and also posts an answer to their own bounty question. Another user also gives an answer.

If there are only two answers and the bounty owner's self-answer has a higher score than the other answer, what would happen in this case? How would the bounty's reputation points get awarded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since bounty owner cannot award the bounty to his/her own answer, so in your given scenario only one answer is left which can receive the bounty. Now if the bounty is not awarded within 7 days (plus the grace period), the other answer will be awarded half the bounty amount automatically (provided it was posted after the bounty started AND has a score of 2 or more). If the answer does not meet this criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.

Bounty owner can accept any answer he/she wants to (including the self-answer) BUT cannot award bounty to  his/her answer.

Answer (score 2):

The OP can always accept their own answer.  Accepting an answer is different than awarding a bounty and has no bearing on if the bounty is given to that answer.  If you award a bounty there is a little blue box that you select on the post that you want to award the bounty to.