# Revert bounty on an unanswerable question?

Tags: discussion, bounty

My title might be a little bit clickbait-y, since I probably already know the answer, but as I am not sure, I still want to ask my question.

I've had a problem with Android Studio closing my open tabs, deleting my favorites, bookmarks etc. so I went and wrote a question:

[Android Studio 2.2.3: Favorites, bookmarks and opened folders keep disappearing, project and .idea-folder are always rebuilt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41615927/android-studio-2-2-3-favorites-bookmarks-and-opened-folders-keep-disappearing)

While researching myself, I've found out, that there is a bug in AS, which makes it impossible to fix my problem. (I want to mention the user Vadim Kotov, who checked if my problem happens on his machine too)

The problem will be fixed in the new release of Android Studio 2.3 which I can't use in my company since the tools we use are predetermined.

I found a workaround (which still might fail horribly if I misclick on the button that causes the original problem), but since nobody was able to answer my question, my bounty will go to waste.

Is it possible to give back the bounty?

I am pretty sure, the answer to this question is 'no', because somebody MIGHT have found a solution, so it's more about the potential help than the actual.

But since I am still small enough that reputation is a concern for me, I just wanted to ask if it is possible to get back the reputation.

Comment: I'm afraid the standard answer is "no", because a bounty is viewed like an advertisement in a newspaper, which is also not refundable if it fails to attract business.

Comment: As to your question: should that **Final update** not be a proper answer?

Comment: @RadLexus - I agree, update 5 and final update are actually the answer and should be in an answer post, not in the question.

Comment: @rad Should that **comment** not be a proper answer? :-)

Comment: @CodyGray: flag declined. It does not attempt to answer the current question :P

Comment: It does. The answer is, you should not give back the bounty because the question is *not* "unanswerable"—in fact, you already have the answer and should post it. "The premise of the question is wrong" is a valid answer. @rad

Comment: Ooh, here's an evil idea: Answer you own question. No idea if it'll work.

Comment: Answering your own question is far from evil, @Blacksilver. Yes, it will work. It's even encouraged.

Comment: I know it's not evil. And by "work" I mean "Award you the bounty".

Comment: I went ahead and wrote an answer, which hopefully might help someone else to at least use the workaround. Losing my bounty - since I think you wont get the bounty yourself - is a pity, but I'll manage to get through that. Thanks for the discussion!

Comment: @Blacksilver You [can't award a bounty to your own answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294803/what-happens-if-a-bounty-is-not-awarded-before-grace-period-on-a-self-answered)

Comment: You can't award it to your own answer, but, the question having an answer is certainly more useful than not. I'd suggest cleaning up your question, there's no reason to have a bunch of "Edit N"'s everywhere, anyone can click "Edited" to see all of the edits. Make the edits part of your question.

Comment: If the question deserved to be closed, you could flag a moderator to cancel the bounty and close it. But your question seems a proper question.

Comment: @KevinB: Good idea, I've cleaned the question quite a lot now and removed the parts that are contained in the answer as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't cancel bounty because you don't like/don't get/no longer need the answer.

You pay bounty for *attention* to your question which *may* result in an answer. There are no guarantees that question will actually get answer, that answer is usable or if you like an answer.

As a sneaky and dangerous alternative to bounty you could have started with [Meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect) instead. Meta effect potentially cheaper than bounty (as you need a lot of downvotes to match 50 bounty points), but you get attention from mostly wrong set of people (once who review questions for quality rather that specifically knowledgeable in given tags)  and less likely to get answer as result of it.